# Computer requires a reboot to get LAN connectivity

Tags: internet, lan

I have a lan adapter connected on my pc. However the first time I power it on it doesnt appear in the adapter setting and I have no internet connectivity. I have to restart the computer for me to get internet connectivity, It then appears in the adapter settings. Could anyone give me some pointers since this as a daily affair is kind of time consuming.

Comment: We need some details to help you. What OS? Is the network adapter part of the motherboard or a separate card? How long has this been happening? Have you updated drivers or BIOS?

Comment: so, when your computer is powered down, it takes two reboots to bring the nic online? if it happens every day, does the nic only remain online for a period of time?

Comment: Computer is powered down, now I start the computer-no nic,restart nic present. Once the nic is present it is works continously till I shutdown my pc

Comment: @CharlieRB , I think its a pci card. I am on windows 7.It happened all of a sudden and has been going on for a week now. Nope , no driver updates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following to determine what is failing.

1. Boot to an Ubuntu Live CD. If the NIC works normally the problem is
   likely with Windows.
2. If the behavior is the same with the Live CD, then move the card to
   a different PCI slot and try again. If that makes no difference,
   update or re-flash the BIOS to rule out a fix or corruption.
3. If the problem still persists, there could be a problem with the
   motherboard or the NIC. Get another NIC card first as they are much
   less expensive to replace.
4. If you replace the NIC and still have the problem, the motherboard
   is failing.